# I want to draw a string in the middle of my screen

Tags: java, int, screen

I want to do

```
thisg.drawString("Hello!" + var, I WANT TO MAKE THIS THE MIDDLE OF MY SCREEN!, mainWindowHeight + 230);
...
```

but there is a  small problem!  But in the code, the variable changes... so the number can be bigger or smaller depending on the user input! So if I set the location to be at a certain spot, and the integer is really big, it goes off the screen! So is there a way that I can set

`I WANT TO MAKE THIS THE MIDDLE OF MY SCREEN!`

code always be set to the middle... no matter what size the int is...

Comment: [Exploding pixels](https://explodingpixels.wordpress.com/2009/01/29/drawing-text-about-its-visual-center/) has a post about this that might help

Answer (score 0):

`Font` has methods to measure the width of a string in pixels. Call this to find out how wide the string will become.

```
int textWidth = g.getFont().stringWidth(...);
int windowWidth = ...;

int x = windowWidth/2 - textWidth/2;
if( x < 0 ) x = 0; // make sure text doesn't disappear
```

Comment: I don't understard... can I give you more code and you can work it out for me?

Comment: Here you go: `int textWidth = g.getFont().stringWidth("$" + (df.format(accountWorth)), (Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getWidth() / 2), mainWindowHeight + 230));
   int x = mainWindowWidth/2 - textWidth /2;
   if( x < 0 ) x = 0; // make sure text doesn't disappear
   g.drawString("$" + (df.format(accountWorth)), (Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getWidth() / 2), mainWindowHeight + 230);`